# Problem with dynamic scroll views iphone

Tags: iphone, dynamic, view, scroll

I was looking for an answer to my problem all over the net but with no succes. I am using a view with a toolbar with 3 buttons. In a view is a scrollview. Whenever i tap one of the buttons, scrollview is populated with a number of labels and textviews with dynamic size and position. depending on the ammount of text that was parsed. The size of scroll view (height) is also dynamicly changed depending on the size of its subviews. It all works good when i just switch toolbar buttons without previously scrolling the view. But if i scroll a view to the bottom, and then by clicking button i change positions and size of text and labels, the scrollview is acting strange and is not returning to its previous position (content offset 0, 0). I was wondering if there is a good waz to make this work more smootly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply set the contentOffset of the scroll view at the same time you are settings its new content, i.e.

```
// populate your scrollView and set its contentSize
// ...
[yourScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Comment: tnx for reply. zeah, i am using it, and it works well if i change from "smaller" scrollview, but if i scroll down when mz scrollview is bigger, then it doesn/t wok. mz whole scrolview begins to jump around.